# Future in callback run in the same thread

Tags: scala, future

When i run this code:

```
val intList = List(1, 6, 8)

val listOfFutures = intList.map{
  i => future {
    println("future " +i)
    Thread.sleep(i* 1000)
    if (i == 12)
      throw new Exception("6 is not legal.")
    i
  }

}
val futureOfList = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)

futureOfList onSuccess{
  case int => {
    logInfo("onSuccess")
    int.foreach(i => {
      Future{
      logInfo("h : " + i)
      }
    })
  }
}

futureOfList onFailure{
  case int => {
    logInfo("onFailure")
  }
}

logInfo("after")
```

The nested futures run all with the same thread:

```
future 1
2013/11/24 11:55:00.002 [ModelUtilsTest] [main]: INFO: [] after
future 6
future 8
2013/11/24 11:55:14.878 [ModelUtilsTest] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]: INFO: [] onSuccess 
2013/11/24 11:55:15.378 [ModelUtilsTest] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]: INFO: [] h : 1 
2013/11/24 11:55:15.378 [ModelUtilsTest] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]: INFO: [] h : 6 
2013/11/24 11:55:15.378 [ModelUtilsTest] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1]: INFO: [] h : 8
```

Why it is happen? i need the inner future to run in parallel.

Comment: You're only logging the thread on the callback, not on the thread that is doing the work.  Try changing the `println` to `logInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Future` implementation checks whether it is going to run something on the `ForkJoinPool` that owns the current thread.  In that case, it will `ForkJoinTask.fork()`, which adds the new work unit to the work queue of the current worker thread.  Any other thread has to steal that work to execute it.  You wouldn't expect to see a uniform distribution of your tasks over the available threads, especially with trivial tasks.

In the following run, `worker-9` bears the brunt:

```
scala> val f = Future sequence (1 to 20 map (i => Future(i)))
f: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@47fe4ff8

scala> f onSuccess { case is => is foreach (i => Future(println(s"$i on ${Thread.currentThread}"))) }

scala> 2 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
5 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15,5,main]
4 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
6 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
1 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main]
12 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
11 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
15 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
16 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
17 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
18 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
19 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
20 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main]
3 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
10 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main]
9 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11,5,main]
8 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
7 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15,5,main]
14 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
13 on Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main]
```

Comment: The code I wrote is only samlpe. this is happen even if the task is an IO task and long execution. i see only one thread from the pool running all the inner tasks.

Comment: @igreen If you post a self-contained example, with versions of Scala and Java -- assuming the default context or how it's set up, I'd be happy to try it, for fun.  Something else is going on.

Comment: I can't post self-contained example. this is complicate code. it done some network requests and wait for response. 1. scala 2.10.2 2. `import  ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` 3. Java 1.7

Comment: @igreen In your example output, are all threads in the pool busy (because of the complicated app your example is embedded in)? In that case, your one worker will happily work through its own queue of tasks before another worker is available. (You can test that by creating a private executor and running your futures on it; thread scheduling will affect the test, but if the futures do real work, you'd see some in parallel.)

Comment: I add sleep(1000) in the start of the future and it run in parallel. So your answer is right. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to achieve parallelism easily:

First, you can use the `traverse` method from the `Future` companion object.

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val modifiedList = Future.traverse(myList)(myFunc)
```

Or you can use `par` collections, which run the mapping in parallel.

```
val modifiedList = myList.par.map(myFunc)(breakOut)
```

Comment: as som-snytt wrote the par won't help.